# How can I use outputcache at this situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

In my application, I will remember user's language choice in session.
The problem is if I use output cache, then the change language function will not work, because it caches the result when I retrieve from database according to the Session["lang"] value.

So if I have another method to use cache function ?  Or how can I decrease the response time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the Output Caching infrastructure is the VaryBy mechanism, which is a way to instruct ASP.NET to keep parallel caches of the same page varied by some piece of data, like a querystring. In this case, the VaryByCustom mechanism may be the simplest to implement. [Here's a short article with a good example.](http://visitmix.com/labnotes/Using-VaryByCustom-With-OutputCache-in-ASPNET-MVC-To-Support-Caching)

First, the caching attribute:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "CachedPage")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

The cache profile:

```
<caching>
    <outputcachesettings>             
        <outputcacheprofiles> 
            <add varybycustom="Language"
                 varybyparam="*"
                 duration="86400"
                 name="CachedPage" />
        </outputcacheprofiles> 
    </outputcachesettings> 
</caching>
```

And finally, the custom logic in global.asax.cs:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(
    HttpContext context,
    string arg)
{
    if (arg == "Language")
    {
         return Session["lang"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
    }
}
```

Now for each possible unique value that `Session["lang"]` returns, ASP.NET will keep a cached copy of the page which executed under that parameter.

Comment: I read something like this before, but it seems does not work, it always caches the result.

Comment: @MemoryLeak when implemented correctly I assure you it works quite well.

Comment: I found the Context.Session is null, it is not supposed to be null ! What's up ?

Comment: @MemoryLeak - You cant access Session in `GetVaryByCustomString`, it's not there yet  - it's created in `Application_AcquireRequestState`. Try using something else for the vary-ator (is that a word?). URL/Cookies maybe?

Comment: oh, is there any other choices ? As I have implemented all the logic, I don't want to change it, yup, it's a string.

Comment: Downvoted because Session is not available in GetVaryByCustomString, as AcquireRequestState hasn't yet fired.

Answer (score -1):

Save this value in cookies, session are not available in GetVaryByCustomString

Comment: That should be comment.